# Ruby On Rails routing error - No routes matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

I know there are many questions opened before with same title, but I could not able to find suitable answer for my situation.

URI: `http:// localhost:3000/user/register`

error: `No route matches {:action=>"about", :controller=>"user"}`

log:

```
Processing by UserController#index as HTML
Rendered user/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 82ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"about", :controller=>"user"}):
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__379156404_34959024'
```

My Routes:

```
Sample::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "site#index"

  get "site/index"

  get "site/about"

  get "site/help"

  get "user/index"

  get "user/register" => "user#register"
```

Ruby Version: `ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]`

Rails Version: `Rails 3.2.11`

Please help me in solving this routing problem.

Comment: Please show line 14 at app/views/layouts/application.html.erb :)
I think there is a wrong link

Comment: <%= link_to_unless_current("About",  {action: "about"}) %> |

Comment: use: <%= link_to_unless_current("About", {controller: 'site', action: "about"}) %>

Comment: rails use current controller if you are not defined

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be `get "user/register" => "users#register"`?
Controllers are usually plural.

Comment: Rake Routes output `root     /                        site#index
   user_index GET /user/index(.:format)    user#index
user_register GET /user/register(.:format) user#register
   site_index GET /site/index(.:format)    site#index
   site_about GET /site/about(.:format)    site#about
    site_help GET /site/help(.:format)     site#help`

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice your controller is singular.